# Saiku Hierarchize function not returning expected cellset

Tags: rest, mdx, mondrian, saiku

Can someone explain me why this `mdx` query executed against Saiku `rest api` does not return expected `cellset`? This query is executed as `mdx` type `ThinQuery`.

```
SELECT 
  {
    [Location.CountryHierarchy].[Croatia]
   ,[Location.CountryHierarchy].[Serbia]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,Hierarchize
  (
    Union
    (
      {
        [Product.ProductHierarchy].[Drinks]
       ,[Product.ProductHierarchy].[Food]
      }
     ,[Product.ProductHierarchy].[Drinks].Children
    )
  ) ON ROWS
FROM [Sales cube];
```

Expected output(tested with jpivot, pivot4j and Pentaho SchemaWorkbench/MDX explorer)
[ExpectedResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13lS7.png)

Actual result rendered on Android OLAP client am working on - just to be sure I also checked returned json from saiku server and really cells are missing.
[Actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLZWk.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are executing using the execute endpoint and passing MDX or a Query Model in, you need to play with the properties section, try this:

```
"properties": {
    "saiku.olap.query.automatic_execution": true,
    "saiku.olap.query.nonempty": true,
    "saiku.olap.query.nonempty.rows": true,
    "saiku.olap.query.nonempty.columns": true,
    "saiku.ui.render.mode": "table",
    "saiku.olap.query.filter": true,
    "saiku.olap.result.formatter": "flat",
    "org.saiku.query.explain": true,
    "org.saiku.connection.scenario": false,
    "saiku.olap.query.drillthrough": true
  }
```

Comment: Hi magicaltrout, thx for reply. I tried adding both properties flat and flattened but result is the same. Here is properties json snippet: "properties": { "org.saiku.query.explain": true "saiku.olap.query.drillthrough": true "org.saiku.connection.scenario": false "saiku.olap.result.formatter":"flattened" }

Comment: Thank you very much for your input you had right filing about properties. At first was very scared that i broke something while stripping down Saiku server for my needs :). I looked at generated json on try.meteorite.bi and just copied the whole properties seciton... I'll edit your answer with full properties section.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try adding in the `[ALL]` member for Food to force the issue?

This was my AdvWrks mock-up:

```
SELECT 
  {
    [Product].[Category].&[4]
   ,[Product].[Category].&[1]
  } ON 0
 ,Hierarchize
  (
    Union
    (
      {
        [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[Australia]
       ,[Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[Canada]
      }
     ,{
        [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[Australia].Children
       ,[Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[Canada].[All]
      }
    )
  ) ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE 
  [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount];
```

So in your scenario:

```
SELECT 
  {
    [Location.CountryHierarchy].[Croatia]
   ,[Location.CountryHierarchy].[Serbia]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,Hierarchize
  (
      {
        [Product.ProductHierarchy].[Drinks]
       ,[Product.ProductHierarchy].[Food]
       ,[Product.ProductHierarchy].[Drinks].Children
     }
  ) ON ROWS
FROM [Sales cube];
```

Comment: Hi, so I tried to execute the query but i get this exception:
MondrianException: Mondrian Error:MDX object '[Product.ProductHierarchy].[Food].[All]' not found in cube 'Sales cube'

Just to mention, [Food] is member of Level [Category level] and because of that I think you can't use [All] because it does not exist.

Comment: unusual hierarchy - Drinks is a level but Food is just a member?

Comment: Drinks and Food are both Members belonging to Level [Category level]. Below [Category level] in hierarchy is [Product level] with some other Members.

Comment: @xyman I edited and deleted the `Union`: are you able to add a screenprint showing the complete stucture of `[Product.ProductHierarchy]`?

Comment: Here is the [screen print](http://i.imgur.com/RgZ9WSM.png?1) of query but result is not ok

Comment: I agree with @whytheq with the MDX.
On try.meteorite.bi open a sales cube and run: 

    WITH
    SET [~COLUMNS] AS
        {[Store].[Stores].[Store State].Members}
    SET [~ROWS] AS
        {[Product].[Products].[Product Department].[Beverages], [Product].     [Products].[Product Department].[Dairy]}
    SELECT
    NON EMPTY [~COLUMNS] ON COLUMNS,
    NON EMPTY Hierarchize({[~ROWS], [Product].[Products].[Product     Department].[Beverages].children}) ON ROWS
    FROM [Sales]


Which seems to return what you want.

Comment: If the answer is correct, can you mark it so please! :)